# How do I keep my folding bed side rail up?

Tags: wood-repair

I have made a platform bed with protruding bedrails. (All 3 sides except headboard side) I have made them foldable by placing hinges between bedrail and bedframe. So it flips up and comes down at 90 degree back to it's place. I am done with everything it's just that when I lift it up how do I keep it straight at it's place?? (On top of the bed frame!?/ Parallel to bed frame)
Thanks in advance!![image][image][image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. A photo or two would definitely help here, I *think* I know what you're asking about but I can't be sure. If it's not clear from the photos what material you used, thickness etc. would also be useful details to add into your Question.

Comment: If not a photo, how about your drawings?

Comment: Alright, sure. Lemme try.

Comment: Hopefully this elaboration would work.. a big thanks for your time and suggestions y'all kind hearted gentlemen 

Comment: Thanks for the photos, they help a lot. My first thought was you could just use dowels to physically hold the hinged portion up. Instead of dowelling it may be cheaper and more convenient where you are to buy replacement broom handles instead, which are approximately the diameter I'm thinking would be suitable. The dowels would slip into holes drilled fairly deeply into the frame (perhaps 2" / 50mm) and project upwards most or all of the height of the fold-up portions, so each dowel would be perhaps 14" / ~350mm long. You'd get three of these per broom handle. How does that sound?

Comment: So but how would the dowels/broom handle take its position when the bedrail is down.

Comment: Thanks much for your help Graphics!!

Comment: To lower the bed sides you just pull the dowels out of the drilled holes and put them somewhere convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You say that 3 sides fold up, but you didn't show the detail of how the end/side interface works. However, I'm thinking that some sort of decorative hook & clasp might work to hold them in the "up" position.

Something like this:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of Lowes.com. No recommendation of vendor or individual product implied or intended. For search term purposes, they call it a "gate hook and eye".</sup>

You would attach the hook to the *edge* one piece and the loop to the *edge* of the other, then fold up one corner and hook them. Fold up the other corner and hook them, as well, and all 3 sides should stay up.

Of course, you also don't indicate what will be happening when they're up (using it to keep sleeping toddlers from rolling off?), so this may not be secure enough for your purposes, but it will hold. Of course, you don't indicate if you want a hidden solution, which this would not be.

I used a similar one, though smaller and made of brass, to hold the doors closed on a display case I made a few months back. It was quite suitable for the light duty I had in mind, this one appears to be much sturdier and may be more suitable for your purposes.

Comment: But this puts the holding mechanism on the face of the folding portions doesn't it? That might be awkward for the user!

Comment: It does, @Graphus, but the OP didn't really specify the use case beyond "hold folding edges in a folded position". This suggestion will do that. The under side of the folding flaps isn't finished to the same level as the top side, so the aesthetics aren't of the _highest_ priority (not that there's anything wrong with what's been done), so having a bit of nice looking hardware on the outside might not be too big a concern. I figured it was a viable option.

Comment: Actually, not on the _face_, but on the edge (when folded flat). This would, I suppose, become the "face" when the flaps are folded up.

Comment: But one edge (end) interacts with another board and another would be facing outwards so in one case visible and potentially a snag hazard and in the other would prevent the boards from folding down into the in-service position..... no? If mounted on the underside a solution something like this seems like it could work, but it has to reach around a corner so to speak, which I think points to one easy option — a door chain :-)

Comment: @Graphus It appears that both sides fold up. I _presume_ the foot-end also folds up. While the boards are in the folded up position, sit the "eye" piece on the folded up side, screw it down. Set the "Hook" piece on the folded up foot (ensuring that the hook makes it into the eye), screw it down. When you release the catch, both pieces can be folded down. The eye will stick out 1/2" or so on the side, and the hook will stick out 1/2" or so off the end. Again, we don't know the use case or final aesthetic, so we don't know if this is acceptable for the OP or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favourite web client to search for terms like: click-clack hinge, sofa bed mechanism, etc.

There are many variations on these, but the idea is that they are a hinged locking mechanism with two (or more) resting positions.

Whether or not you can find a set that match your aesthetics is up to you. There are some that are meant to be exposed.

Alternatively, you could make a set of simple wooden "locks", either on a pivot (i.e., like a barn door or outhouse "lock") or by passing a small beam through two metal or wood brackets. The latter is sort of like those door braces you see in movies depicting medieval castles, which they close to keep out the marauding hordes.

Comment: Alright..lemme try that! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Magan if you'll take a few moments to take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thank you" is to click the up arrow next to any and all answers that help you, and the check mark next to the one that helped the _most_.

Comment: And why is it NOT the "proper" way to say thank you by actually writing thanks to the useful reply!